# Java BoxProject using two classes

Tags: java

Im trying to get this code to print out new boxes based on my original Box class and im stuck.  I am not sure what variables i need to specify in my Grid Class.  Nor do I know what to put in the  following class.

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt)  {
    // maybe do stuff here
    repaint(); 
  }
```

Here are both of my classes.

---The code has been updated since first reply---

Box Class

```
import java.awt.*;

public class Box{

  int upperLeftX = 0;
  int upperLeftY = 0;
  int height = 20;
  int width = 20;
  Color color = Color.RED;

  //constructor
  public Box(int i, int j, int k, int l, Color m) {
    upperLeftX = i;
    upperLeftY = j;
    height = k;
    width = l;
    color = m;
  }

  // paints the box on screen
  public void display(Graphics g)
  {
    g.setColor(color);
    g.fillRect(upperLeftX,upperLeftY,width, height);
  }

  // getters and setters
  public int getUpperLeftX() {
    return upperLeftX;
  }

  public void setUpperLeftX(int upperLeftX) {
    this.upperLeftX = upperLeftX;
  }

  public int getUpperLeftY() {
    return upperLeftY;
  }

  public void setUpperLeftY(int upperLeftY) {
    this.upperLeftY = upperLeftY;
  }

  public int getHeight() {
    return height;
  }

  public void setHeight(int height) {
    this.height = height;
  }

  public int getWidth() {
    return width;
  }

  public void setWidth(int width) {
    this.width = width;
  }

  public Color getBoxColor() {
    return color;
  }

  public void setBoxColor(Color color) {
    this.color = color;
  }

}
```

Grid Class

```
import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class Grid extends Applet implements ActionListener{
  // declare variables here
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt)  {
    // maybe do stuff here
    repaint(); 
  }

  public void paint(Graphics g)   {   
    Box box1 = new Box(0,0,40,40,Color.WHITE);  
    box1.display(g);
    // do more stuff here
    Box box2 = new Box(40,40,40,40,Color.WHITE); 
    box2.display(g);
  }

}
```

Comment: How are you stuck? What do you want to achieve? What happens instead?

Comment: The assignments in your constructor for `Box` are backwards. You want to assign the passed-in values to the object's fields, not the other way around.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, `Box` should not extend `Applet`. In fact, it should probably not extend anything at all. It should only serve as a storage container for some data about the boxes. This will not affect anything, it just is confusing and doesn't make sense.

Second, as Dan455 has pointed out, the assignments in the `Box` constructor are in the wrong order. This would cause no harm, except the parameters passed to the constructor would be mysteriously ignored, and it would seem like every `Box` was constructed with `new Box(0, 0, 20, 20)`.

Third, as for the `ActionListener`, you don't need to add it unless you have something that responds to an `ActionEvent`. If the arrangement of the boxes needs to change, you should have an array of boxes that are all drawn in `paint`, and if the display of boxes needs to be updated, you can modify the array and call `repaint`, which will call `paint` as soon as possible.

Comment: @Behe - I cannot get new boxes to be drawn on the screen.  When I compile and run the applet starts and displays a blank screen.

Comment: Ive removed the import of Applet and have reworked my Box constructor to be the other way around.  However the applet returns a blank white screen. Do i have to add more variable definitions to the Grid class?  And can you give an example as to what I need to put in the repaint function?  Thanks

Comment: As for the `repaint` function, it is a very big mistake to override it. It performs several tasks that you really don't want to interrupt by overriding `repaint`. So if you are redefining `repaint` delete your definition. If your problem still presists, I can't help you, except by completely rewriting your code for you, which I don't have time to do.